# Cycling through array goes over the count of elements

Tags: c, dwm

I have this array:

```
static const Layout layouts[] = {
    { "[]=",      tile },
    { "><>",      NULL },
    { "[M]",      monocle },
};
```

This function should cycle through the array:

```
int
cyclelayout(const Arg *arg) {
    static unsigned short int layout = 0;
    if (++layout >= sizeof(layouts)/sizeof(layouts[0])) {
        layout = 0;
    }
    setlayout( &((Arg) {.v = &layouts[layout]}));
}
```

When it is called it should set next layout or return to 0 if it goes beyond array elements. but it goes over the array elements and the program crashes. I cant figure out whats wrong?

Arg and Layout:

```
typedef union {
    int i;
    unsigned int ui;
    float f;
    const void *v;
} Arg;

typedef struct {
    const char *symbol;
    void (*arrange)(Monitor *);
} Layout;
```

Complete program:
[dwm-6.0](http://dl.suckless.org/dwm/dwm-6.0.tar.gz)
[dwm-6.0-cyclelayout.patch](http://bpaste.net/show/119663/)

Comment: cyclelayout() should return an `int`, but it returns nothing. So either make sure it returns something, or change the return type from `int` to `void`. This isn't guaranteed to solve your problem, but at least it solves the problem of you asking two different questions here (the one in the title of your question and the other one in the question itself.)

Comment: Please post a complete program one can compile and run.

Comment: Are you serious? That's a **window manager**. Post a complete program one can compile **and run**. That's without having to start a whole new X11 session, without having to comb over the code to make sure it's not a trojan, and please make sure your results are reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

```
int  // This says to return an int.
cyclelayout(const Arg *arg) {
    static unsigned short int layout = 0;
    if (++layout >= sizeof(layouts)/sizeof(layouts[0])) {
        layout = 0;
    }
    setlayout( &((Arg) {.v = &layouts[layout]}));  // This doesn't look like valid C to me?

    return 4;  // http://xkcd.com/221/
}
```

If your function should "cycle through an array", shouldn't it have a loop somewhere?

Loops come in the flavors:

```
for
do-while
while
```

I don't see *any* of those keywords in your function, so I conclude it doesn't "cycle" through anything.

Comment: Function should set next layout when called but return to 0 when it goes beyond the table elements.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

- you have an hidden if/else construct there, `setLayout` is part of the `else` clause, it's not a real error but you have something that is implicit and not readable to anyone, not explicit
- you are using a pre-increment operator `++variable` which returns a reference and not a copy of the object like the post-increment operator `variable++` does, it's probably not the "quantity" that you want to use in a comparison
- you are not returning any value considering that you have declared to return an int in the signature for your function

It will also help to know what is `Arg` and `Layout` as a type.